# C# success message after data was inserted in xml file

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to try catch an error and showing a success message if save was true in an xml file but I do not know the way around it. Can anyone help. Below is the code which i have:

dataentry.cs

```
 try
        {
            teacher.Save();
            if ()
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Teacher saved!!!","Success");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception errorSave)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with savin file", "Error" + errorSave.Message);
        }
```

person.cs

```
protected void Save(string typeName)
    {
        string targetDirectory = CreateTargetDirectory(typeName);

        //2. Generate the path to the target file
        string filePath = targetDirectory + ID + ".xml";

        //3. Serialise the object
        //4. Save the object to the target file
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

        using (FileStream dataStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(dataStream, this);
            dataStream.Close();
        }

    }
```

teacher.cs

```
 public class Teacher:Person
{

    public void Save()
    {
        Save("teacher");
    }

    public static List<Teacher> Load()
    {
        return Load<Teacher>("teacher");
    }

    public decimal RatePerHour { get; set; }
    public List<string> ClassNames { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the trouble you're having?

Comment: I am trying to try catch that the data has been saved in xml file when the user hits the save button. If it was succesful a mesdsage is shown to him above the form and if not an error message is given to him the same  way

Comment: You'll either need to make changes so that `Save` returns some sort of success/error indicator that you can check afterward, or just skip the if altogether. It does not appear necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
bool isSuccess = false;
string resultMessage = "File save {0}. {1}";

try
{
    teacher.Save();

    isSuccess = true;
    resultMessage = string.Format(resultMessage, "succeeded", string.Empty);
}
catch(Exception errorSave)
{
    //Log error here

    //Set response message
    resultMessage = string.Format(resultMessage, "failed", errorSave.Message);
}
finally
{
    MessageBox.Show (resultMessage, isSuccess? "Success" : "Error");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `teacher.Save();` throws an exception, the subsequent lines within the `try` block will be skipped.

If `teacher.Save();` does not throw an exception, you can assume the save was successful.

These two things mean you do not need an `if` statement around the success message box.

```
try
{
    teacher.Save();
    MessageBox.Show("Teacher saved","Success");
}
catch(Exception saveError)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Problem saving file", "Error" + saveError.Message);
}
```

Comment: If I do if(teacher>save()){  };   it is giving me an error though in visual studio itself

Comment: "you do not need an if statement"

Comment: no success message is given with the above solution but xml file is being generated and data saved in it

Comment: If no message box is being shown, it is likely the above is not being hit. To confirm, put your cursor on the `teacher.Save()` line, and hit F9 to place a breakpoint. Then hit F5 to debug your application. If the breakpoint is hit, the application will pause, and there is a problem with MessageBox.Show.

Comment: You were right. I was not doing the try catch on the wanted save button it seems...apologies